# MTR results to json with php

Tags: php, json, regex

I'm creating a system for work where I will have VMS around our multiple locations and I'll have a central page where you can enter an IP and it will pull all the MTRS from the remote ones and dump the results.

I'm thinking the best way to accomplish this is would be to make a call to a page on the remote server which will start the MTR and then provide the results in Json,

My issue I'm struggling with is how to break up the different values and metrics in the MTR into different objects in the JSON array. I've considered regex but I feel like that has to be a better way. ALl help is appreciated.

example MTR for discussion.

```
Start: Fri Apr 21 01:56:17 2017

HOST: MTR-DC08                             Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev

  1.|-- dc03r04ds36.scalabledns.com           0.0%    10    0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.0

  2.|-- dc08mx01.scalabledns.com              0.0%    10    0.8   1.1   0.8   2.0   0.0

  3.|-- enzu.com-gw.lax.ip4.zayo.com          0.0%    10    0.8   1.2   0.8   2.6   0.5

  4.|-- ae16.cr1.lax112.us.zip.zayo.com       0.0%    10    1.0   1.4   1.0   2.5   0.3

  5.|-- ae9.mpr1.lax12.us.zip.zayo.com        0.0%    10    1.0   1.0   1.0   1.2   0.0

  6.|-- ae7.edge2.LosAngles.Level3.net        0.0%    10    1.0   1.6   0.9   6.8   1.7

  7.|-- ae-1-60.edge3.LosAngeles1.Level3.net  0.0%    10    1.1   2.8   1.1   9.1   2.6

  8.|-- a.resolvers.level3.net                0.0%    10    1.0   1.0   1.0   1.1   0.0
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Exactly the MTR I posted above.

Comment: I am actually on a similar project. You have a server part and a front page. Communication is through websockets tho other solutions like rest api etc could be added. Right now I am implementing persisting the generated data. End goal would be to have something like ping plotter in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the `-j` flag or `--json` on the mtr command, your output will be JSON. No regex required.

```
$: mtr -j 8.8.8.8

{"report": {
   "mtr": {
     "src": "me",
     "dst": "8.8.8.8",
     "tos": "0x0",
     "psize": "64",
     "bitpattern": "0x00",
     "tests": "10"
   },
   "hubs": [{
     "count": "1",
     "host": "???",
     "Loss%": 0.00,
     "Snt": 10,
     "Last": 1.58,
     "Avg": 19.83,
     "Best": 1.48,
     "Wrst": 183.60,
     "StDev": 57.54
   },

[...]

   {
     "count": "10",
     "host": "google-public-dns-a.google.com",
     "Loss%": 0.00,
     "Snt": 10,
     "Last": 32.19,
     "Avg": 31.02,
     "Best": 25.18,
     "Wrst": 55.12,
     "StDev": 8.87
   }]
}}
```

See the man page for all the supported options: https://www.mankier.com/8/mtr#-j

In more complicated environments that have multipath routing, you may want to consider **Dublin Traceroute** (https://dublin-traceroute.net) rather than mtr. Again, output is in JSON so it should make it easy for your to parse the hops.